# Cassandra roll back with when inserting into multiple tables

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I am writing data into tables in cassandra. If i am wirtinh data into one table and then the second transaction fails then how the data is rolled back in first table?

Comment: As per response below, there is no way to achieve this. But if you are using java, you could give a try to [ScalarDB](https://github.com/scalar-labs/scalardb) a try. They are bringing transactions into Cassandra world.

Answer (score 0):

It is not rolled back. There is no such mechanism to achieve that. Closest you can get are logged batches in combination with lightweight transactions.